# Unable to run JUnit 5 test in IntelliJ 2018.2.2 w/ Gradle 4.9

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, junit5

I'm attempting to run a single JUnit 5 unit test from Intelli 2018.2.2 Community Edition. The project is using Gradle v4.9.

For whatever reason, when attempting to run the test method individually or as a test class, the same output results:

```
Aug 29, 2018 3:37:47 PM 
org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: MinHeapTest
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.lambda$getJavaClass$0(ClassSelector.java:73)
at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.getJavaClass(ClassSelector.java:72)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.lambda$resolve$3(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:69)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolve(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:68)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:50)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:61)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:82)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:52)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Aug 29, 2018 3:37:47 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: MinHeapTest
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.lambda$getJavaClass$0(ClassSelector.java:73)
at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.getJavaClass(ClassSelector.java:72)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.lambda$resolve$3(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:69)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolve(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:68)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:50)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:61)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite.
```

Running `gradle test` on the command line runs just fine.

The Gradle configuration is:
    apply plugin: 'java'

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I've read about vaguely similar issues w/ IntelliJ 2016, but not more recent builds.

Anyone else run into this issue? Seems like InteliJ is using some other means to launch the tests than Gradle, but its unclear what.

For good measure, I checked [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=%22org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException:%20Could%20not%20load%20class%20with%20name:%22) for similar stack traces to no avail.

Pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Can you please your setting in IntelliJ ? You must open the Preferences or Settings dialog window. There you can search for Gradle and then look for Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner and Select Gradle Test Runner.

By default it is Platform Test Runner

Comment: That'll work! Not sure what's up with IntelliJ's platform runner, but if I can run my tests I'm happy. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, turns out this doesn't enable debugging. May well be that the Platform test running is required for IntelliJ debugging.